# my button pop-up keeps pushing the page to top when i close it

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to make a simple text pop-up button using just html and CSS. I looked at a bunch of examples but most of them use JavaScript in some way so I cant use them. found some that is pure CSS but when I tried them, they all do this weird thing where closing the pop-up brings me to top of page. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hjrudc5n/

This is my HTML

````
```
    <div class="box"><a class="button" href="#popup1">Show Overlay</a></div>
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
<h2>Title</h2>
<a class="close" href="#">×</a>
<div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
````

and this is my CSS

```
    /*pop up overlay */
.box {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.popup .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: that is because your are using `anchor tag` for close button the default behavior of anchor tag is redirecting. You can use `JS` to solve this or you can use `button` instead.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://dev.to/tayfunerbilen/popup-with-pure-css-1m4k

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/aj43psdw/13/

The problem with your code was that using "#" as an href will always take you to the top of the page, no matter what. Also, makes thing hard to control.

What you can do. is work with labels and checkboxes, and control the "state" of things via that.

Like this:

```
  [name="popup"]{
     width:0;
     height:0;
     overflow:hidden;
     position:relative;
     z-index:-1;
     pointer-events:none;
  }

  [name="popup"]:checked ~ .overlay{
     visibility: visible;
     opacity: 1;
  }
```

In the fiddle I linked you, clicking the button will check the checkbox, that we'll show via css. the X button will do the same, unchecking it.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of `href="#"` of the anchor tag you were using, which led to going to top of page on closing the popup.
A workaround is to use `<input type="checkbox" />` (so that you can use [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) selector) along with `<label>`(so that you can still interact with checkbox after hiding it), to hide, and unhide the popup.

```css
/*pop up overlay */
.box {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#pop:checked + .overlay {    
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.popup .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#pop{
  display: none;  /*Hide the checkbox*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><label class="button" for="pop">Show Overlay</label></div>
<input type="checkbox" id="pop" />
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <label class="close" for="pop">×</label>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @wswswswsws Please check if it works for you.